# Best practice for threading in a Web API

Tags: c#, multithreading, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple Web API with a single `GET` controller only. The GET controller reads XML data and returns it in JSON format.

The `GET` API is supposed to be excessed every minute but in case if there is no GET request for more than 1 minute then I need to start backing up the data (simply in XML format..nothing fancy).

**My GET Api**

```
        //GET api/
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {            
            try
            {
                //Read XML
                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\myfile.xml");


                //Convert XML data into JSON string
                string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xDoc);
                JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);

                return Ok(json);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }                     
        }
```

**Sample XML:**

```
<CurrentStatus>
    <Time Stamp= "20181011133631244">
        <price>12</price>
        <amount>100</amount>
    </Time>
</CurrentStatus>
```

**Sample Backup in XML:**

```
<CurrentStatus>
    <Time Stamp= "20181011133631244">
        <price>12</price>
        <amount>100</amount>
    </Time>
    <Time Stamp= "20181011133633354">
        <price>11</price>
        <amount>120</amount>
    </Time>
    <Time Stamp= "20181011133633204">
        <price>15</price>
        <amount>90</amount>
    </Time>
</CurrentStatus>
```

**My Planned Logic:** I am planning to declare a `static` variable `_lastAccessedTimestamp`, which will be monitored by a separate thread. If `currentTime - _lastAccessedTimestamp` > `1 min` then start backing-up the data.

**Question:** Good-practice to implement threading in Web API for this kind of scenario (or any other better option)?

**PS:**  Web Service will run on a localhost IIS server.

Comment: How will you host this? In a Windows Service?

Comment: @nvoigt: Sorry, I forgot to provide that info. Updated in my question.

Answer (score 2):

After each request I would set/reset a timer for 1 min. Having a variable that you poll from a different thread is not efficient and it raises other problems.

Even more, you can use a proper job handling lib (like Hangfire - https://www.hangfire.io/) so you can just schedule a job (after 1 min) and reschedule it after each request, in case a new request comes.

Be aware that IIS can stop your process at any time, you might want to look into that.
http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

For the implementation, you can use a middleware/filter that does this at the end of each request automatically. No need to add this in the controller. It's also easier to add multiple controllers without duplicating the code.

Comment: To use `Hangfire`, do I need to install some server (Hangfire server) also. Sorry, I don't know much about this.

Comment: No, you don't need to install a server. Check the quick start guide: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/quick-start.html Hangfire could a bit overkill for your situation...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like Hangfire to fire off a task, and then that task can be handled by something. That could be a console app, another web application, an Azure Function, whatever. The point is that it's external to your main web application. Then, you can immediately return, without waiting for that thing, whatever it is, to finish. You can, also, utilize something like SignalR and web workers to push status updates to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using `System.Timers.Timer`. Further reading here -> [Time Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Please know that my answer uses dependency injection but could easily be refactored to instantiating normal classes.

I would Implement a timer service which is configured using an interval in your case 1 minute. Im going to share my timer implementation below , it is registered in the dependency injection container as a singleton but should give you something to work with.

```
 public class TimerService : ITimerService
{
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private  DateTime _startTime = DateTime.Now;
    private double _timerSettings;

    public TimerService()
    {
      _timer = new System.Timers.Timer
        {
            AutoReset = true,
            Interval = 60000,
        };
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
           //Backup Data method here
            _startTime = DateTime.Now;
        };
    }

    public double GetTimerInterval()
    {
        return _timer.Interval;
    }

    public void StopTimer()
    {
        if (_timer == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Timer not primed.");
        }
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        if (_timer == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Timer not primed.");
        }
        _startTime = DateTime.Now;
        _timer.Start();
    }
}
```

On application start you must kick off the timer , after every minute it will start doing the backup of data. Due to the `AutoReset = true`.

Now simply reset the timer in your controller

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class XmlController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITimerService _timerService;

    public XmlController(ITimerService timerService)
    {
        //Injected in
        _timerService = timerService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ProccessXML(object someXMLObject)
    {
        _timerService.StopTimer();
        SomeMethodWithXml(someXMLObject)
        //Reset Timer
        _timerService.StartTimer();
        return Ok();
    }


}
```